# mysql/mariadb information_schema view creation time

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, information-schema

I want to find all tables and views created before a certain timestamp. For tables it is easy, just

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'TABLE' AND create_time < :ts
```

But for views it is not so simple. The `create_time` column is null for all the views in `information_chema.tables`. e.g.

```
MariaDB [MYDB]> SELECT IF(create_time IS NULL, 'Null', 'Not Null') AS has_create_ts
                     , COUNT(1)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'VIEW' GROUP BY has_create_ts;
+---------------+----------+
| has_create_ts | COUNT(1) |
+---------------+----------+
| Null          |       70 |
+---------------+----------+
1 row in set, 10 warnings (0.371 sec)
```

And the `information_schema.views` table does not have any timestamp columns.

So how can I find out when a view was created? Or is it just not possible.

If it matters database version is:

```
MariaDB [MYDB]> SELECT VERSION();
+--------------------+
| VERSION()          |
+--------------------+
| 10.3.7-MariaDB-log |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.392 sec)
```

Comment: File a "feature request" with MySQL and/or MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I find out when a view was created? Or is it just not possible.

No, this is not possible.

A view does not actually contains data, it just made of a definition, ie a SQL statement that references data contained in *real* (physical) tables : hence this is all that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` can show you.

Comment: But doesn't mysql/mariadb record when that definition was created? Other databases do (Oracle and Vertica are two I have used in the past).

Comment: @Sodved : I see your point... But AFAIK no MySQL does not store that information.